# Firebase web push notifications show up twice

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

Using firebase-messaging.js v8.2.0 and using onBackgroundMessage to show notification, the notification is being sent 2 times, the default one and the onBackgroundMessage one.
What are your thoughts abou this problem? Code is same as documented in the firebase mesaging quickstart sample

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you are getting no answers this is usually due to the fact that you have not asked in a very clear and detailed way. Please add more information then you will have a better impact.

Comment: I have the same issue. let me know if you have found anything.

Answer (score 0):

I changed one of firebase notification scripts code. There was an unexpected bug which is sending the notification two times. I can send you the files. Meanwhile, this is my firebase-messaging.sw.js (I hided the keys).

```js
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("firebase-messaging.js");

/*
Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the messagingSenderId.
* New configuration for app@pulseservice.com
*/
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
  console.log("[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ", payload);
  // Customize notification here
  let url = payload.data.notification_url;
  const notificationTitle1 = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions1 = {
    body: payload.notification.body,
    icon: "",
    data: { url: payload.data.notification_url },
    image: payload.notification.image
  };
  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle1, notificationOptions1);
});
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function (event) {
  let url = event.notification.data.url;
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(
    clients.matchAll({ type: "window" }).then(windowClients => {
      // Check if there is already a window/tab open with the target URL
      for (var i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
        var client = windowClients[i];
        // If so, just focus it.
        if (client.url === url && "focus" in client) {
          return client.focus();
        }
      }
      // If not, then open the target URL in a new window/tab.
      if (clients.openWindow) {
        return clients.openWindow(url);
      }
    })
  );
});
```

The file I changed is firebase-messaging.js and saved it into the sites static files with the changes I made. Let me know if you need it.